# Why object does not exist in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I load a page, where I have a line:
`<script>HUD = "hello";</script>`, then I open the page, open DevTools, go to Console" and type in `HUD` - I see

`VM331:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: HUD is not defined(…)`

Then I reload the page, keeping the DevTools open, then enter HUD again - now it exists and prints "hello"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

    <script> 
        var HUD = "hello";
        console.log(HUD);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 Open console and enter HUD - is it there?
</body>
</html>
```

Run the snippet and check it this way - sometimes HUD exists, sometimes it does not. I wonder why...

See the screenshot of js fiddle, that proves the point:
[image: you can use HUD, but it still does not exist for DevTools]

Comment: HUD is a string? What do you expect calling a string to do?

Comment: It should print "hello" to the console.

Comment: Sometimes it prints it, sometimes it says "HUD is not defined" for some reason.

Comment: Why this question is downvoted?

Comment: Have your tried console.log(HUD);? It makes no sense to invoke a string.

Comment: I don't know. Someone did it just in case, to show off.

Comment: Remove the `var` and it will work.

Comment: It makes sense, this is how DevTools works. You enter a title of an object or invoke a function - and it prints the result, either the contents of an object or what function returns.

Comment: Why would it work if I remove var??? I declared it in a global scope!

Comment: @evolutionxbox, it worked not because you removed "var". It worked only because sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. No matter if you declare it as "var" or not - in this scope it must become window.HUD anyway!

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that this useless variable may be optimized away by the JavaScript engine ([this behavior is mentioned in the console documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Examine,_modify,_and_watch_variables#Examine_variables)).

Some solutions to fix it and prevent its removal:

- set it explicitly as `window` property: `window.HUD = "hello";`
- include it in a no-op operation: `(function(v){ if (!v) die(); })(HUD);` (this one is more dangerous, as a smarter engine could detect it's still not really used)

Note that this probably isn't a real problem: once this variable starts to be useful (i.e. It's potentially used somewhere in the code), the engine won't delete it anymore and you'll be able to see it in the console without trick.

Comment: Your answer does makes sense. Would appreciate if you prove that with a fiddle. I tried https://jsfiddle.net/jm7e57jL/2/ , no luck :(

Comment: @GopinathShiva Fiddles are framed, hence you have several window. Try it here: https://dystroy.org/pub/test.html

Comment: Appreciate that. Could you please provide an example showcasing declaring global variable using var (global scope). That would complete the purpose of the question asked

Comment: Deleted my answer as @DenysSéguret's is spot on. It should be marked as correct.

Comment: No, it should not be marked as correct, because it the example on dystroy.org/pub/test.html still gives me "VM124:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: HUD is not defined(…)". Give me a moment, I'll upload it...

Comment: @DenysSéguret, here is the link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54313720/devToolsIssue/index.html and here is the screenshot of what I did: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hve9w7s8vvlwph/Screenshot_52.png?dl=0  As you can see, even intensive usage of the variable does not help whatsoever.

Comment: @shal Don't use jsbin but an independant page (see previous comment)

Comment: @DenysSéguret, I did not use jsbin, I used dropbox with my own independent page.